# Error messages when using IDE for CS50 Problem Set 1

Tags: c, cs50

I'm taking CS50 and am struggling with Problem set 1. I have created the directories needed to execute the hello.c file, but it won't display and I keep getting the same error. Sorry if my code isn't structured properly, but could someone please point me in the right direction? Below is my terminal code, I am using IDE to execute.

```
~/ $ mkdir ~/pset1/

~/ $ cd ~/pset1/

~/pset1/ $ mkdir ~/pset1/hello

~/pset1/ $ cd ~/pset1/hello

~/pset1/hello/ $ ls

~/pset1/hello/ $ clang hello.c

clang-7: error: no such file or directory: 'hello.c'
clang-7: error: no input files

~/pset1/hello/ $
```

Comment: As ``clang`` says there is no file ``hello.c``. I can see similar reported when you do ``ls`` (prints no files).

Comment: the `ls` command you ran should have shown if the `hello.c` file resided within `/pset1/hello` (note use `ls -alh` to show hidden files); if it didn't list the file then it doesn't belong within that dir hence the error. You could run `locate hello.c` to see where/if it is located somewhere else on your file-system & then either change to that dir or move the file to your current working directory

Comment: You need to create the C file *before* you compile it. I think you're skipping steps here. You've made a directory, gone into it, but next you need to create that file and put some C code in it.

Comment: I tried both those recommendations, thankyou, but it still won't locate hello.c. I have saved hello.c file in ~/pset1/hello/ but it will not show. Is there a way to delete code from my terminal or do I have to create a new terminal to start again?

Comment: Okay @tadman so I need to create new file and save as hello.c before I write anything in the terminal?

Comment: Yes. You can't compile code you don't have. Not before "anything" but specifically before `clang hello.c`

Answer (score 0):

You skipped the step where you create hello.c, which is this one:

**Shall we have you write your first program? From the File menu, click New File, and save it (as via the Save option in the File menu) as hello.c inside of your ~/pset1/hello directory. Proceed to write your first program by typing precisely these lines into the file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Notice how CS50 IDE adds “syntax highlighting” (i.e., color) as you type, though CS50 IDE’s choice of colors might differ from this problem set’s. Those colors aren’t actually saved inside of the file itself; they’re just added by CS50 IDE to make certain syntax stand out. Had you not saved the file as hello.c from the start, CS50 IDE wouldn’t know (per the filename’s extension) that you’re writing C code, in which case those colors would be absent.**

Once you do this step, you can continue with

```c
 ls
```

and then

```c
clang hello.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that hello.c is saved within hello (which is within pset1). It may be that when you saved the file, you saved it inside pset1 without saving it within the hello folder.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).